# Expanding use of Javascript array.reduce helper method

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

**Background**

I am following a course on Udemy which goes over all of the ES6 features. In one of the lessons the instructor talks about using the reduce helper method to solve the popular balance parenthesis interview question.

I can solve this without the reduce method. Although with the reduce method it does get the job done in less code. I have been asked to find the depth of the parenthesis in an interview before and was wondering if this could all be done in the same method using reduce.

I do not know why this addition to the question confuses me so much but I would like to learn.

**Problem**

I have been trying to figure it out for a while and it might be my lack of understanding how reduce works.

**Example**

This uses reduce to return true of false regarding if the parenthesis or open and closed evenly.

```
function balanceParens(string) {
    return !string.split("").reduce((counter, char) => {
        // Handle if parens open and close out of order
        if (counter < 0) { return counter; }
        // Add 1 for each open in order
        if (char === "(") { return ++counter; }
        // subtract 1 for each close in order
        if (char === ")") { return --counter; }
        // handle use case if char is not a paren
        return counter;
    }, 0);
}
console.log(balanceParens("((()))"));
```

**Question**

How would I return the max depth of the parenthesis using the reduce helper method.

Comment: Actually reduce was introduced in ES5…

Comment: How would you solve the problem without `reduce`? If you can post your loop code, we can help you transform it into `reduce`.

Comment: Yes it was introduced in es5. But the course if over es6 and this was just something he was talking about in the es6 course.

Comment: @Bergi when I get home I can post a solution not using reduce. But it will be a few hours.

Comment: Generally when you have something that fits the pattern of `.reduce()` but you need multiple values, you just use an object as the reduce target.

Comment: @Bergi TIL reduce was in spec version 5.1 :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could maintain current depth and max depth while reducing.

```js
function maxDepth(string) {
    return string.split("").reduce(({current, max}, char) => {
        // Handle if parens open and close out of order
        if (current < 0) return {current, max}
        // Add 1 for each open in order
        if (char === "(") return { current: current + 1, max: Math.max(max, current + 1)}
        // subtract 1 for each close in order
        if (char === ")") return { current: current - 1, max}
        return {current, max}
    }, {current: 0, max: 0}).max;
}
console.log(maxDepth("(((()))(((())))()(((((()))))))"));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is perfect can now see my problem. Man I was so close.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a compact version that returns `NaN` when the parentheses are not balanced. It uses nested functions in a functional style:

```js
function maxDepth(string) {
    return ( ([depth, max]) => depth ? NaN : max )
        ([...string].reduce(([depth, max], ch) => 
            (newDepth => [newDepth, newDepth < 0 ? NaN : Math.max(max, newDepth)])
                 (depth + (ch === "(") - (ch === ")"))
        , [0, 0]));
}
console.log(maxDepth("(((()))(((())))()(((((()))))))"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should answer it!

```js
function balanceParens(string) {
    let max = 0;
    let res = string.split("").reduce((counter, char) => {
        // Handle if parens open and close out of order
        if (counter < 0) { 
          return counter;
        }
        // Add 1 for each open in order
        if (char === "(") {
          if(++counter > max) {
            max = counter;
          }
          return counter;
        }
        // subtract 1 for each close in order
        if (char === ")") {
          return --counter;
        }
        // handle use case if char is not a paren
        return counter;
    }, 0);
    console.log("Max depth was :", max);
    return !res;
}
console.log(balanceParens("((()(((())))))((((()))))"));
```

Comment: What do you mean? `const` variables where?

Comment: I like this answer. It seems more consistent with the question example.

Comment: @AftabKhan For `max` specifically

Comment: @Arrow Not sure what you mean by "consistent"

Comment: @Bergi Why should I make it const when it's value is changing?

Comment: @AftabKhan I'm suggesting that you should not change it when using `reduce`

Comment: Any specific reason why?

Comment: @Arrow Mutating some state outside of a reducer is not really "consistent" :)

Comment: @Bergi  because this solution simply increments a counter while the other increments a counter and uses Math.max.

Comment: @AftabKhan Because immutability is the whole point of using `reduce` for the `counter` as well

Comment: I didn't understand that. Counter is one single accumulator, whose value keep changing for every iteration.

Comment: @Bergi but reduce has an array callback which can mutate the original arrray. You can't say that the whole point of reducing is immutability unless I'm missing something I am unaware of?

Comment: Asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44956739/array-reduce-mutating-state-outside-is-not-recommended) if anyone is interested to give an elaborate answer

Comment: @Bergi your argument also seems absurd because reduce takes an initial argument which it frequently mutates.

Comment: @Arrow No, the accumulator (or the array) is *not* mutated. The `counter` doesn't change. It's a new one for every invocation of the callback, which itself is a pure function.