# Array.reduce mutating state outside is not recommended?

Tags: javascript

Why is mutating variables outside `.reduce()` method considered bad practice? In the example below I am mutating a variable declared outside from inside the reduce method. Why is it not recommended to do so?

```js
function balanceParens(string) {
    let max = 0;
    let res = string.split("").reduce((counter, char) => {
        // Handle if parens open and close out of order
        if (counter < 0) { 
          return counter;
        }
        // Add 1 for each open in order
        if (char === "(") {
          if(++counter > max) {
            max = counter;
          }
          return counter;
        }
        // subtract 1 for each close in order
        if (char === ")") {
          return --counter;
        }
        // handle use case if char is not a paren
        return counter;
    }, 0);
    console.log("Max depth was :", max);
    return !res;
}
console.log(balanceParens("((()(((())))))((((()))))"));
```

Comment: If you do that, why bother using `reduce` at all? If your output is via side-effects you might as well be using `forEach`.

Comment: My question is not around whether I should use `forEach` or `reduce`. I simply want to know why is it bad to have side-effects.

Comment: Related: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/15269/why-are-side-effects-considered-evil-in-functional-programming https://stackoverflow.com/questions/763835/are-side-effects-a-good-thing

Comment: That was what I was looking for. @JordanRunning

Comment: Please consider deleting this question, as it's not useful for future StackOverflow readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is mutating variables outside `.reduce()` method considered bad practice?

Because you are mixing the functional with the imperative approach. Keep it to a single paradigm instead of confusing everyone.

You would go with

- either `reduce` with a pure callback and [no side effects](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/15269)

  ```
  function step({max: oldMax, counter: oldCounter}, char) {
    const counter = oldCounter + (char=="(") - (char==")");
    const max = counter > oldMax ? counter : oldMax;
    return {max, counter};
  }
  function maxParensLevel(string) {
    assert(hasBalancedParens(string));
    const {max, counter} = string.split("").reduce(step, {max:0, counter:0});
    return max;
  }
  ```
- or a simple loop and two mutable variables

  ```
  function maxParensLevel(string) {
    assert(hasBalancedParens(string));
    let max = 0;
    let counter = 0;
    for (const char of string.split("")) {
      if (char == "(")
        counter++;
      else if (char == ")")
        counter--;
      if (counter > max)
        max = counter;
    }
    return max;
  }
  ```

but not both.

Answer (score 0):

See @JordanRunning comment:

*"If you do that, why bother using reduce at all? If your output is via side-effects you might as well be using forEach"*

I was about to say the same. And here is a version of the function without an external dependency:

```js
function balanceParens(string) {
 let res = string.split("").reduce((state, char) => {
  // Handle if parens open and close out of order
  if (state.counter < 0) {
   return state;
  }
  // Add 1 for each open in order
  if (char === "(") {
   if (++state.counter > state.max) {
    state.max = state.counter;
   }
   return state;
  }
  // subtract 1 for each close in order
  if (char === ")") {
   state.counter = --state.counter;
   return state;
  }
  // handle use case if char is not a paren
  return state;
 }, {max: 0, counter: 0});
 console.log("Max depth was :", res.max);
 return !res.counter;
}

console.log(balanceParens("((()(((())))))((((()))))"));
```

Comment: I know this can be achieved without having to use max. I wanted to know if there is any specific reason why I shouldn't. Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44956127/2876143) to solution which IMO is more cleaner